# SQL connection failing to one database but connecting to another database on the same sql instance

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, connection-string

I have an asp.net app that I am using to connect to a `SQL server` instance to retrieve data. We have our `DB` that I can access and we have a second db that I cant access. The connection strings are exactly the same the only thing that changes is the database name.

```
data source ='X3V7TRN\SAGEX3'; initial catalog = 'FailedDB'; User ID ='dva'; Password = 'xxx'; Max Pool Size=1024; Pooling=true

data source ='X3V7TRN\SAGEX3'; initial catalog = 'SuccessfulDB'; User ID ='dva'; Password = 'xxx'; Max Pool Size=1024; Pooling=true
```

When I open the connection to the second database ('`SuccessfulDB`') I can connect as expected, but when I try to connect to the first database it jumps to a catch and I get the error "Login failed for user dva" I've tried with the SA account, another sysadmin account and I have created an account and set it as the '`FailedDB`' owner, but still no luck...

Comment: the user dva does not have rights to access the other db

Comment: and if you try thye faulty credentials with SSMS you can connect? If not,  you dont have the permission to access that database...

Comment: Please check if you are able to connect to the database using SQL Server Authentication from SQL Server Management Studio using the same credentials.

Comment: I can login using ssms with the credentials that I tried to use in the config file

Comment: Sometimes; it is caused because of the IIS express which runs underneath. Restart IIS and check or if you are in debug mode, close it and run the app again.

Comment: Hi All, I found the issue, it was a collation conflict between the login and the db. After changing the collation of the DB it was all good!